# Use mytop as a root user, without specifying a database

Tags: mysql, centos7

Is it possible to use `mytop` without specifying a database? That is to say, can I use it as a root mySQL user, in order to monitor all of the databases on the server?

For example, I can use the same credentials with `mysql`, like this

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

which prompts me for my password. However, I've yet to find the same thing for `mytop` (found nothing related to this in the `man mytop`).

I have tried using it like this

```
mytop -u root -p<mypass>
```

Of course, this doesn't work, and it tries connecting to a non-existing DB (taken from the config file).

How can I use `mytop` as a root user, without specifying a database?

Comment: [digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mytop-to-monitor-mysql-performance) had a nice tutorial for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, it's not possible to do it.

A database **must** be specified, but if the mysql root parameters are used, every connection will be visible in mytop.